# how to pass variables in the urls in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

i tried to pass variables in url in django but it keeps getting 404 error

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from test_url import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^detail/<int:id>/',views.detail)
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.
def detail(request,id):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>{}.</h1>".format(i
```

Comment: `return HttpResponse("<h1>{}.</h1>".format(i` is missing a closing `))` but I don't suppose the server would run if you tried. 404 for _what URL_?

Comment: yes, it's my bad. copoying and pasting process caused this fault. even though it's complete, it doesn't work

Comment: We've established that it doesn't work. You've still not said anything about the particular circumstances or the error

Comment: my app just contains these two lines of code as i'm only trying to test this concept

Comment: This is my last go. I asked it in my first comment about a typo that you still haven't [edit]ed. What URL?

Comment: return HttpResponse("<h1>{}.</h1>".format(id))

Comment: this is the last line that misses the closing brackets and the id word

Comment: What is the URL you are typing in your browser to get the 404 response?

Comment: http://localhost:8000/detail/3/

Comment: If you add a slash at the end: localhost:8000/detail/3/